# Overwriting the List type of the parent class to avoid casting when calling methods

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have an input file (text => `TextFileImporter` or xml => `XmlFileImporter`) which contains data with different structures. A structure is described in the `Definiton` class, so my `FileImporter` object holds multiple instances of `Definition`.

A `TextFileImporter` should hold `List<TextDefinition>` and a `XmlFileImporter` should hold `List<XmlDefinition>`.

Please have a look at the example code:

```
// Parent classes
abstract class Definition {}

abstract class FileImporter {
  protected List<Definition> definitions;

  public FileImporter(List<Definition> definitions) {
    this.definitions = definitions;
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    // use 'definitions'
  }
}

// Text files
class TextDefinition extends Definition {
  public void copyLine() {}
}

class TextFileImporter extends FileImporter {
  // here should be clear that 'definitions' is of type List<TextDefinition>
  // to call 'copyLine()' on its items
}

// XML files
class XmlDefinition extends Definition {
  public void copyNode() {}
}

class XmlFileImporter extends FileImporter {
  // here should be clear that 'definitions' is of type List<XmlDefinition>
  // to call 'copyNode()' on its items
}
```

As you can see on the basis of the comments I'm not sure how to handle that preferably. Of course I first need constructors. Then, I don't want to cast each item of `definitions` to the suitable subclass every time just to call a method.

Can I make a reasonable use of generics here? Or is there another solution?

Comment: I would add a type argument to `FileImporter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to introduce some generics.

```
// Parent classes
abstract class Definition {}

abstract class FileImporter<T extends Definition> {
  protected List<T> definitions;

  public FileImporter(List<T> definitions) {
    this.definitions = definitions;
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    // use 'definitions'
  }
}

// Text files
class TextDefinition extends Definition {
  public void copyLine() {}
}

class TextFileImporter extends FileImporter<TextDefinition> {
  // here should be clear that 'definitions' is of type List<TextDefinition>
  // to call 'copyLine()' on its items
}

// XML files
class XmlDefinition extends Definition {
  public void copyNode() {}
}

class XmlFileImporter extends FileImporter<XmlDefinition> {
  // here should be clear that 'definitions' is of type List<XmlDefinition>
  // to call 'copyNode()' on its items
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great!